# How to pass a list of values into a crystal report

Tags: java, jsp, crystal-reports

I have a list of integer values(employee IDs) which i need to pass to a Crystal Report.
I am using a Action class to pass these values.
So far i have succeeded with passing a single value but i couldn't find a way to pass a list of values.

```
Fields fields = new Fields();
Values vals1 = new Values();
ParameterFieldDiscreteValue pfieldDV1 = new ParameterFieldDiscreteValue();

pfield1.setName("fromDate");
pfieldDV1.setValue(start_Date);

vals1.add(pfieldDV1);
pfield1.setCurrentValues(vals1);
fields.add(pfield1);

CrystalReportViewer viewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
//some code to set CrystalReportViewer settings
viewer.setParameterFields(fields);
```

By this way i was able to get the fromDate value into the Crystal Report.
Does any one know how to get a this kind of list

```
int employeeList[]
```

Or a

```
String[] empListOptions
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach (string in string_array)
        {
            param.Value = string;
            report.ParameterFields[parameter].CurrentValues.Add(param);
        }
```

Found here: http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=227