# How to set mutiple values for a parameter of type number

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have been able to pass multiple values to a parameter of type string using the following code:
`JOIN({?particulars},ChrW(13) )` in formula field.

However, if I try to do the same for a parameter of type number:

```
JOIN({?amount},ChrW(13) )
```

I get the error:

> *A string array is required here.*

How can I use formula to pass multiple values to a parameter of type number?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than messing around splitting & joining why not pass the values "properly"? See my answer to [How to pass a list of values into a crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401421/how-to-pass-a-list-of-values-into-a-crystal-report/13414757#13414757)

foreach (string in string_array)
        {
            param.Value = string;
            report.ParameterFields[parameter].CurrentValues.Add(param);
        }