# Crystal Reports with WCF webservice as datasource

Tags: wcf, crystal-reports

I have two following objects: Assignment and Billing

[image]
The `GetAssignments` method returns a list of `Assignments` and what I want is to get a `Billing` for every `Assignment`. `GetBillingByAssignmentId` takes an integer `AssignmentId` as parameter.

From what I have read from different sources is that its not supported by the CR. Therefore I Changed the `GetBillingByAssignmentId` to take list of integers as parameter.

Now the problem is how do I pass a list of integers as parameter to `GetBillingByAssignmentId` from CrystalReports.

Is it even doable? If so then please do point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No feedback recieved so I came up with a work around to midigate my Problem. Its not an elegant solution but it works.

First I concatenated The Assignment and the Billing Objects into one Master object so that all information is contained in one object called Assignment.

Secondly I changed the parameter of the GetAssignments method to take a string and not List of integers. And then from Crystal reports viewer when user is prompted for a value the user can type comma seperated list of Assignment Ids. The web service splits the Assignmend Ids and returns the List of Assignment objects.

The 'Allow multiple values' option in Edit parameter window in crystal reports viewer is greyed out and is not supported/always false when using webservices as datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my reputation I can't add comment, so replying here..

Please check [How to Pass a list of values into a crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401421/how-to-pass-a-list-of-values-into-a-crystal-report), this might be helpful to you...

Comment: Thanks for the answer nirav but i am looking for a way to Pass My Parameter from Crystal reports designer to a WCF service.